# mathabx package preventing \not inside subsection title

Tags: incompatibility, mathabx

I'm writing an article in which I want the title of one of my subsections to be $n\not\equiv_41$. When I put that in though, I get the error message

```
Undefined control sequence.
\not #1->\let \@@not
                     =\not \let \@@n =\n \let \not =\relax \let \n =\relax \...
```

Troubleshooting a bit, I find that there is some conflict between using \not inside the subsection, and using the mathabx package.

For instance, I can typeset any one of the following 3 things.

```
\documentclass{amsart} %not using mathabx
\begin{document}
\subsection{$n\not\equiv_41$}
\end{document}

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$n\not\equiv_41$ %not putting this in a subsection title
\end{document}

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\subsection{$n\equiv_41$} %erasing the \not
\end{document}
```

But I cannot typeset this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\subsection{$n\not\equiv_41$}
\end{document}
```

Is there some other way to cross out my $\equiv$ symbol inside the subsection title and still use the mathabx package? Or do I have to choose between the title I want and the stuff in the article that I'm using mathabx for?

Comment: Yes there is: use `\notequiv`, or the alias `\nequiv`.

Comment: @Bernard Awesome, that does it! Also, unless you're expecting this question to be closed I think you should post that as an answer. I don't know if this will be of interest to others but it is certainly specific enough to not be a duplicate. Either way I am happy to get on with my article, thanks.

Comment: Use `\protect\not` when in a moving argument (such as a sectional title).

Comment: @egreg This looks like a solution to a more general problem, maybe this should be "the" answer?

Comment: @j0equ1nn Engaged in other business, now. I’ll turn in later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mathabx` version of `\not` is fragile, so it should be protected in moving arguments, such as sectional titles and captions, by prefixing it with `\protect`. So

```
\section{$n\protect\not\equiv_41$}
```

You can, however, make it robust at the outset:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathabx}

\MakeRobust{\not}

\begin{document}

$n\not\equiv_41$

\section{$n\not\equiv_41$}

\end{document}
```

For completeness, here's how `mathabx` could define `\not` in a more robust and efficient way:

```
\makeatletter
\def\strip@bs{\expandafter\@gobble\string}
\DeclareRobustCommand\not[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{not\strip@bs#1}
    {%
     \@ifundefined{n\strip@bs#1}
       {\notsign#1}
       {\@nameuse{n\strip@bs#1}}%
    }
    {\@nameuse{not\strip@bs#1}}%
}
\makeatletter
```

Comment: Congrats on passing the 600K rep mark!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it doesn't work, but it's simpler to use the pre-defined command `\notequiv` or its alias `\nequiv`.